# Hasse principle for a group

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

$\DeclareMathOperator\PSL{PSL}$In the paper [Ono - "Hasse principle" for $\PSL_2 (\mathbb Z)$ and $\PSL_2(\mathbb F)$](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/proceedings-of-the-japan-academy-series-a-mathematical-sciences/volume-74/issue-8/Hasse-principle-for-mathrmPSL_2-leftmathbf-Z-rightandmathrmPSL_2-left-mathbfF_p-/10.3792/pjaa.74.130.full) there's a definition of a **Hasse principle for a group $G$**, but I don't completely get it. Is there a more motivated reformulation of this definition?

Why I am interested: local–global principles are often very interesting in arithmetic geometry, so when I noticed a paper with this title I looked at it to see whether this proves something geometric.

As said [below](https://mathoverflow.net/a/10557), one can formulate a problem of computing a group $\mathrm{Sha}$ defined by a $g$-module $G$ and a family of subgroups $h_i\in G$, but the actual computation in the paper is for a specific choice of $h_i$, and I can't parse if there is an application of interest. Is it so?

(I suspect this problem arises when you try to prove Hasse principle for equations, like $x^n = a$ but with different Galois groups, see [Ono and Terasoma - On Hasse principle for $x^n = a$](https://doi.org/10.3792/pjaa.73.143), though the results there have a mistake, corrected in the next one)

Comment: Could you give the definition in your question, or is it too involved?

Comment: I put it in my answer.

Comment: @Ilya: regarding your edit, I looked up some related papers of Ono, and I can see now that the problem is related to a certain Hasse Principle for algebraic curves of higher genus (the connection is via the automorhism group as a Galois module).  When I get the chance I will write more about this.  But in the future, please respond to answers by commenting on them, rather than (just) by modifying the question.  For instance, the site alerts me to the former automatically, but not the latter.

Answer (score 7):

Given a group $g$, a possibly nonabelian $g$-module $G$, and a family of subgroups $(h_i)_{i \in I}$ of $g$, Ono defines a pointed Shafarevich-Tate set, say $(S,0)$.  He says the Hasse Principle holds for $G$ (with respect to the data of the $g$-action and the set of subgroups ${h_i}$) if the $S = {0}$.

Namely, for each subgroup $h_i$ of $g$ there is a restriction map in Galois cohomology

$r_i: H^1(g,G) \rightarrow H^1(h_i,G)$.

(The restriction map is defined on one-cocycles merely by pulling back by the inclusion map $h_i \hookrightarrow g$.)  Restriction carries the distinguished (trivial) class to the trivial class.

Then $S$ is defined as the intersection of the kernels of all the $r_i$'s.  Evidently the 
trivial class $0$ lies in $S$, so $(S,0)$ is a pointed set.

All of the above was just a detailed review of the beginning of Ono's paper.  Now let me explain why this generalizes the notion of the Shafarevich-Tate group of an abelian variety A over $\mathbb{Q}$ [or take a more general global field, if you like].

The Shafarevich-Tate group $Sha(A,\mathbb{Q})$ is the set of all principal homogeneous spaces (henceforth phs) $X$ under $A$ which have $\mathbb{Q}_p$-points for every prime $p$ and also $\mathbb{R}$-points.  Because the automorphism group of a phs under a group $A$ is just $A$ itself, by [what I call] the first principle of Galois cohomology, the pointed set of all phs under A is isomorphic to the Galois cohomology set

$H^1(\mathbb{Q},A) = H^1(\mathfrak{g}_{\mathbb{Q}},A(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}))$,

where $\mathfrak{g}_{\mathbb{Q}} = Aut(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ is the absolute Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}$.  [Since $A$ is commutative, the $H^1$ is itself a commutative group, whereas for nonabelian $A$ it would in general be only a pointed set.]

Thus here we have $G = A(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})$ and $g = \mathfrak{g}_{\mathbb{Q}}$. What are the $h_i$'s?  For each prime $p$, $h_p$ is the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, 
viewed as a subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$ (i.e., as a decomposition group at $p$) via choosing an embedding of the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ into the algebraic closure of $Q_p$; also we define $h_{\infty}$ to be the restriction to the subgroup generated by a complex conjugation, i.e., a group isomorphic to $Aut(\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R})$.  A cohomology class lies in the kernel of $h_p$ iff the corresponding phs acquires a point after base extension to $Q_p$ (and similarly for $h_{\infty}$.

Thus the Shafarevich-Tate pointed set of $A$ is indeed a special case of Ono's construction.

That's the motivation I can give you.  As to exactly why Ono's particular choice of Shafarevich-Tate set for an arbitrary group $G$ -- namely take $g = G$ with the conjugation action, and let $(h_i)_{i \in I}$ be the family of cyclic subgroups of $G$ -- is interesting and natural...I can't help you there, and I'd like to know myself.

Why are you interested in this paper?